# HTTP methods to be supported for CRL downloading

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, http, crl

I was not able to find anywhere in the RFCs which HTTP methods must be supported by the conformant CAs in order to allow users to download CRL.

What are the mandatory HTTP methods (GET, HEAD, ...) for CRL?

Comment: Without deeper knowledge on this topic, *downloading* a CRL seems to imply *GET*. Also, this question may be on the brink of off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC (to be precisely, RFC5280) doesn't define required protocols to be supported by CA for CRL/CRT download. It must be defined in a form supported by both, client and server. Thus, HTTP is not mandatory (though, recommended) at all. Major crypto clients (including CryptoAPI) use GET method to retrieve CRL/CRT files.

Comment: RFC 5280 defines media type to be used by the HTTP server implementation. Why description of HTTP method is missed still not clear.

Do you think it is a miss?